# Invalid argument(s) 'fast_executemany' sent to create_engine()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a piece of code that dumps a dataframe with 30k rows into a table on my Vertica database. But since its taking way too long to run, I'm trying to use `fast_executemany` parameter of sqlalchemy.

```
engine = sa.create_engine(('vertica+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER%3D%7Bvertica%7D%3BSERVER%3Djsvertica%3BDATABASE%3Dpw%3BUID%3Dusername%3BPWD%password%3B'),
                            fast_executemany=True,)# connecting to Vertica using SQL Alchemy
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Invalid argument(s) 'fast_executemany' sent to create_engine(),
using configuration VerticaDialect/QueuePool/Engine.
Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fast_executemany` is apparently not implemented in the Vertica dialect for SQLAlchemy. In order for that option to be recognized the dialect would have to be modified similar to the way SQLAlchemy's built-in `mssql+pyodbc://` dialect supports it. But before doing that the developers of the Vertica dialect would want to confirm that the Vertica ODBC driver works properly with `fast_executemany = True` because [not all drivers can use it](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/fast_executemany-support-for-various-ODBC-drivers).